# pyqgis Python API work together with arcpy Python API in the same standalone script

Tags: arcpy, python, pyqgis, python-2.7

I create a simple bat file to create standalone scripts using `pyqgis`.
and that bat work nice .

I follow this [manual](https://mapoholic.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/configure-pyscripter-qgis/)
now I want to use and `arcpy` together in the some script but I don't know how to define correct paths for the `arcpy` to work together with `pyqgis` Python api.

Any idea how to do this with this bat file ?

Practical is two different pythonpaths can i work together ?

I have windows 10 and ArcGIS 10.5.

Here the bat for pyqgis API:

```
set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\PROGRA~2\QUANTU~1
call “%OSGEO4W_ROOT%“\bin\o4w_env.bat
call “%OSGEO4W_ROOT%“\apps\grass\grass-6.4.2\etc\env.bat
set GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\gdalplugins\1.9
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-6.4.2\lib
path %PATH%;”%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27\Scripts\”
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages
set QGISPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis
start "PyCharm aware of QGIS" /B %PYCHARM% %*
```

Comment: I would suppose that this might be difficult since ArcGIS and QGIS both come with their own Python binaries (but I have to admit I haven't tried).

Comment: @Jannes is good question I think